# Entity Framework get table name and properties for model class name string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the files from a directory (DatabaseModels) and get the table name plus properties for a model class name string.

Structure

> - DatabaseModels
>
>   - CalendarItems.cs
>   - ConfigurationObject.cs
>   - ContentBlock.cs
>   - EmailTemplate.cs
>   - NewsItem.cs
>   - Page.cs

```
var fname = string.Empty;
WmoPlatformContext context = WmoPlatformContext.Create();

foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
{
    fname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(fname);

    Type type = Type.GetType(fname, true);
    var o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    var tableName = context.GetTableName<o>();

    PropertyInfo[] propInfos= typeof(o).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

}
```

`o` doesn't work in `GetTableName<>()` and in `typeof()` (error : `o` is a variable but is used like a type) is there any way to make this work?

Comment: change to GetTableName<type>()

Comment: @Nikita same error : `type is a variable but is used like a type`

Comment: change to GetTableName<typeOf(o)>()

Comment: @Nikita gives me still the same error and I think you mean `typeof` instead of `typeOf`?

Comment: yes,did you checked that?

Comment: Yes, I checked with `typeof` but I get the same error.

Comment: do yopu realise fname is a string , resulting type as string & o as string. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I can do for example `GetTableName<Page>` but I want to do `GetTableName<>` and `typeof()` for each filename at runtime , if you have better options to get this to work that's also fine.

Comment: try with o.GetType() instead of typeof()

Comment: That gives an error for GetTableName<o.GetType()> (`Operator < cannot be applied to operands of type method group and Type`) and for `typeof`  the error `type is a variable but is used like a type`